# Is 0.5CossVdc^2 included in Pswitching losses of MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, buck, switching-losses

[This document](https://www.tij.co.jp/jp/lit/an/slvaeq9/slvaeq9.pdf) (page 3) from TI states that switching losses of a High Side (HS) MOSFET (of a Synchronous Buck Converter) are:

[image]

Then is states that another part of the mosfet losses are:

[image]

which correspond to the energy stored in the parasitic capacitor during turn-off.

I assume that, because there is no method of ZVS for HS Mosfet, P_HS_Coss are lost during turn-on.

As I understand it, the TI Application Report states that the total MOSFET losses, apart from conduction losses, include both P_switching and P_HS_Coss. A similar statement is made from [another TI document](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sluu096/sluu096.pdf).

[image]

***Question*: But doesn't P_switching (as defined in the first equation above) include P_HS_Coss?**

**Doesn't the below figure concern the whole MOSFET including its parasitic capacitance?**
If it doesn't, shouldn't MOSFET current be somewhat smaller during Vds rise (as Coss is charging)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Question*: But doesn't P_switching (as defined in the first equation above) include P_HS_Coss?**

No. Section ***2.1 Switching Losses Calculation*** of Application Report SLVAEQ9 (page 3/13) separates MOSFET losses into five constituent parts: switching loss, conduction loss, gate drive loss, output capacitance loss, and LS MOSFET body-diode loss. As you see, switching loss and output capacitance loss are considered independent from one another. I would say, the document separates losses not according to their localization in circuit components, but rather by identifying the timing when the categorized loss occurs and the current path contributing to this power loss category.

Pay attention to 'ss' letters in capacitor \$C_{oss}\$ designation: **C**apacitance_**o**utput-**s**mall-**s**ignal. Maybe not widely known, in a small signal approximation, a "superposition principle" of a certain kind works not only for voltages/currents, but also for power:
$$
V_{tot} = V_{dc} + v_{ac} \\
I_{tot} = I_{dc} + i_{ac} \\
P_{avr} = (1/T)\int_0^TV_{tot}I_{tot}dt = V_{dc}I_{dc} + (1/2)·\text {mag}(v_{ac})·\text {mag}(i_{ac})
$$
because of DC·AC product averages  \$\int V_{dc}i_{ac}dt=\int I_{dc}v_{ac}dt=0\$.

While there is no classical small signal sine waveforms seen among switching waveform timing diagrams, the current flowing through \$C_{oss}\$ is small and high-frequency as compared with a total drain current \$I_{dc}\$, and small-signal considerations are applicable in this scenario. The energy analysis of charging/discharging of MOSFET internal capacitances, as that leading to derivation of equations (9, 10, 11), makes the switching-loss, gate-drive-loss, and output-capacitance-loss contributions easily distinguishable within the total power loss picture.

Non-linearity of MOSFET's internal capacitances can make the analysis more complicated, but general guidelines still hold.

> **Doesn't the below figure concern the whole MOSFET including its parasitic capacitance?** If it doesn't, shouldn't MOSFET current be somewhat smaller during Vds rise (as Coss is charging)?

Yes, the zoomed-in graph of \$I_{ds}\$ is marred with a ripple from \$C_{oss}\$ charging/discharging currents, but possible corrections to power loss figures are negligible when compared with effects of other approximations made in the buck converter efficiency analysis.

---

Examine the MOSFET power losses calculation analysis in application notes of other manufacturers: ROHM Semiconductor's [Switching Regulator IC Series, Efficiency of Buck Converter](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/applinote/ic/power/switching_regulator/buck_converter_efficiency_app-e.pdf), Infineon's [MOSFET Power Losses Calculation Using the Datasheet Parameters](http://application-notes.digchip.com/070/70-41484.pdf), to see the scatter of approaches and approximations to this task.

Compare the timing diagram of ROHM Semiconductors's appnote

[image: ROHMswitchingwaveform]

with that of Infineon's;

compare the switching loss formulas of TI's:
$$
P_{sw} = (V_{in}/2)·(I_o-Δi_{Lpp}/2)·f_{sw}·t_r + 
(V_{in}/2)·(I_o+Δi_{Lpp}/2)·f_{sw}·t_{off}
$$
and that of ROHM Semiconductors's:
$$
P_{SW-H} = (1/2)·V_{IN}·I_{OUT}·(t_{r-H}+t_{f-H})·f_{SW}
$$

The ROHM Semiconductors's list of the main causes of power loss contains nine factors instead of TI's five-item list in Section **2.1 Switching Losses Calculation**; the TI app note does not consider reverse recovery loss and dead time loss, etc. This does not mean that TI's analysis is inferior to ROHM Semiconductors': each of these has its applicability area. Only be aware of assumptions made in the manufacturer's documents.